# Rendering UI with Sciter on top of the window

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I have an 3d game renderer with DirectX 11 - the project also uses WinAPI.

On top of the game, I would like to render HTML/CSS UI with [Sciter](http://sciter.com/) (it's a **single**, full screen game window).

So I initially draw the 3D scene with my `engine->render()`.

And then I draw UI with Sciter (for now it's just `load_file(....htm)`). The problem is, the UI covers the whole window (with white background), and I cannot see the game through UI.

How can I apply transparency to "mask" between UI and what was rendered to window previously?

I have already tried `SciterSetOption(*hwnd, SCITER_ALPHA_WINDOW, TRUE);` but that makes white background transparent for whole window (I see what is behind the window, the desktop - not the 3D scene of mine which also is transparent :/ ).

I set `html, body { background-color: transparent; }` without result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to render your UI in separate window as Sciter is capable of rendering HTML/CSS stuff directly inside DirectX 3D scene:

[image]

Check http://sciter.com/sciter-and-directx/ article.